# C/Linux - Server <-> Terminal communication with named pipes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, bash

I am working on a project for college where I can ONLY use named pipes (mkfifo()) to establish communication between a server and a terminal (both created by me).

There are:

- Only 1 server;
- 1 or more terminals;

Actually my application works like this:

[image]

- The terminal send a **command_t** structure through a named pipe (**in red**) to the server. This named pipe is a FIFO and it is shared between all terminals. After sending the command_t strucutre the terminal will try to read the reply from another named pipe (**in blue**) and it will be blocked until the server writes something in that pipe.
- The server reads from the named pipe (**in red**) and processes the commands received (command_t structure) by the first come, first served basis. **There are several threads which means several request are processed at the same time.**
- After processing the command the server sends a **reply_t** structure through another named pipe (**in blue**).

**The problem:**

If I start the server with only one thread this all works fine because the responses (reply_t) are sent in the order of arrival of the commands (**command_t**)

But if I start the server with more than one thread I can´t guarantee that the responses are sent in the same order of arrival of the commands and this will make me have mixed responses (something like, I will receive on Terminal 1 the result of the execution from the command from Terminal 2 and etc...).

I was thinking about making something like this:
[image]

In this solution I would have an output PIPE for each terminal connected to the server instead of one output PIPE shared between all terminals. But how can I implement a variable number of terminals in C? I can´t even detect when a new terminal opens the input PIPE.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Even if there is only one thread in the server, how do you ensure that the right terminal gets the response considering that multiple terminals can be reading the fifo?

Comment: @kaylum it works because if terminal A sends a command then it will be blocked on the read() function until the server writes something back. If A and B sends a command the first to send the command will be the first to be blocked at the read() function. So when the server writes the response, the terminal A will be the first to read and then the terminal B.

Comment: That's not how things work. Just because one process calls read first does not ensure that it will be woken first. And anyway, you cannot ensure that a process is not suspended after the write and before the read. Multiprocess/threading is hard. There are many race conditions possible as you will undoubtedly discover.

Comment: @kaylum It fails in multi-thread because I can send a command from terminal A and one from terminal B. But if the server finishes executing B first it will send the reply from command B to the terminal A (that is blocked on the read() function)

Comment: @kaylum about that you are right, it can happen if both terminals send a command about at the same time. But I guess that problem would be solved if I had one output pipe for each terminal, am I right?

Comment: Yes it would be. One way to solve that would be to have each process send a "hello" to the server which includes the fifo to respond on.

Comment: @kaylum I already thought about it. The terminal would create a PIPE and send in the structure command_t the path of that PIPE to the server. But after opening that PIPE once how would I store the file descriptor associated with that path on an array? Since there are no HashMaps in C and LinkedLists are a bit slow to iterate. How would you do this?

Comment: Are you expecting to handle thousands of simultaneous terminals? If not then a linked list is just fine. Or if you really want to optimise then implement your own hash table - it's not that difficult at all. Alternatively, just open/write/close each time.

Comment: "something like, I will receive on Terminal 1 the result of the execution from the command from Terminal 2 and etc.", why don't you use simply an id in your structures `command_t` and `reply_t` , the terminal send a struct with an id_x and after the server process the command it send a reply to the same id_x.

Comment: Do you know how to use `fork`? If so, you can do what a traditional server does, which is to fork a new server process for each terminal. Then that forked process and the terminal that it is talking to can both read and write to the same fifo (the one created by that terminal) because they will be the only two processes using it.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel,

I implemented a similar server before, you can listen a terminal, and when the terminal finishes the message you can fork the process and send the response back on the child process, whereas in the parent process in a loop you create another listener for the next terminal, as ccarton said:

Something like this:

```
while (1)
 {
   newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
               (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
   if (newsockfd < 0)
     error("ERROR on accept");
   pid = fork();
   if (pid < 0)
     error("ERROR on fork");
   if (pid == 0)
   {
     close(sockfd);
     dostuff(newsockfd);
     exit(0);
   }
   else
     close(newsockfd);
 } /* end of while */
```

You can find a complete explanation here: 
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Under "Enhancements to the server code" Section.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to synchronize the server with the terminal is using [System V semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4125/svipc-65382/index.html). The semaphore is taken by a terminal before start "listening" to the channel for "x" minutes. If a message arrive, the terminal process it an send the response back, else, if timeout occurs it just release the semaphore so other terminal can start listening. The problem with this is that you loose the ability to process several message in parallel.

Another approach is as @Moulin said to use an id in (for example the PID returned by `fork()`) in your structures `command_t` and `reply_t`.